# Split String with multiple continuous comma in Java

Tags: java, regex, split

```
String abc = "a,b,c,d,,,";
String[] arr = abc.split(",");
System.out.println(arr.length);
```

Output is 4. But obviously my expectation is 7. Here is my solution:

```
String abc = "a,b,c,d,,,";
abc += "\n";
String[] arr = abc.split(",");
System.out.println(arr.length);
```

Why does it happen? Anyone could give my a better solution?

Comment: correct.. use str.split(",", -1); an overloaded method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [alternative version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) of `String#split()` that takes two arguments to achieve this:

```
String abc = "a,b,c,d,,,";
String[] arr = abc.split(",", -1);
System.out.println(arr.length);
```

This prints

```
7
```

From the Javadoc linked above:

> *If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.*

Comment: +1 for using the overloaded `split()` rather than regex.

Answer (score 4):

You can use lookahead:

```
String abc = "a,b,c,d,,,";
String[] arr = abc.split("(?=,)");
System.out.println(arr.length); //7
```

Comment: This is not the case here, although it works, it complicates the case with regex - specific operator

Comment: What do you mean by that comment and how can simple lookahead becomes complicated?

Comment: Answer is as simple as reading javadoc and adding parameter to `split` call, You don't need to refer to regex cookbook to get this done.

Comment: You seem to be day dreaming. Who referred a regex cookbook here? For unknowns there is no `split` without regex support in Java.

Comment: You know that, I know that, most of Jdevs know that (at least I hope most do)...but not everyone, and using this solution requires to know not only most basic regex rules but also groups and lookahead operator

Comment: You can fight the battle with OP who tagged the question `regex`. A simple lookahead is understood by anyone with basic knowledge of regex and there are no regex groups here. You probably don't understand lookahead syntax.

Comment: bottom line, is that Your solution does not work, as it appends the delimeter to each element, so please, stop boasting about it.

Comment: Bottom line is it is beyond your understanding, it is for community to see what answer works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
String[] arr = abc.split("(?=,)");
```

to split `abc`

Comment: This is not the case here, although it works, it complicates the case with regex - specific operator

Answer (score 1):

This is because split does not include only trailing empty strings, but if you have `\n` at the end, then the last element is not empty

```
[a, b, c, d, , , \n]
```

Answer (score 0):

split() is coded to that very job.
You can count a character or string occurrence in the below way.

```
        String ch = ",";
    int count = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    int idx;
    while ((idx = abc.indexOf(ch, pos)) != -1) {
        ++count;
        pos = idx + sub.length();
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

This very logic is used in Spring.